# Walk trough Folder - copy Main Folder names, not files and folder in Main

Tags: python

Works perfect for the step how to create all the folder in src = Processing. 
But how can I create - in every just created folder ALL the data (files, folders) in the template. So, do a shutil.copytree within the just created folder(s).

```
   src = "C:/code/CopyFolder/Processing"               # must be the processing folder
dest = "C:/code/CopyFolder/Runs"                    # must be the runs folder
template = "C:/code/CopyFolder/Template"            # source where to get Template files

print src
print dest
print template

listDirs = os.listdir(src)
print listDirs

for i in listDirs:
    os.makedirs(dest + '/' + i) # should i do shutil.copytree() here for copy all files, folders from template in every just created folder?
    print i + " " + "path is created"
    #shutil.copytree(template, dest)
```

Comment: Are there any other files in Processing besides the 5 main directories? If not, then you can create a list of folder names and os.makedirs() them all in a loop. If there are, just cull your list by using os.path.isdir().

Comment: i updated the code, but getting the error 183: cannot create file already exists. is my path writing wrong?

Comment: That is indeed incorrect. os.path.dirname(src) will just give you 'copyFolder', which obviously already exists in the current directory. You want to iterate through the dirs list and join dest to each of those dirs, then makedir() the resulting paths.

Comment: can you give a little tip / hint

Comment: Wait, hold up. I don't think os.walk() is doing what you think it does. os.walk goes recursively through the entire folder structure. Don't you just want the first level below src? Need to clarify this before I answer.

Comment: yes, only the first level

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can list through each directory in your source folder and build up a path for each directory in the destination.

```
import os
from os import path

dest = "C:/code/CopyFolder/Runs" 
src = "C:/code/CopyFolder/Processing" 

src_folders = (
    name for name in os.listdir(src) if path.isdir(
            path.join(src, name)
        )
    )

for name in src_folders:
    directory_path = path.join(dest, name)
    os.mkdir(directory_path)
```

Answer (score 1):

os.walk() is unnecessary here, since you just want the first level.

```
src = "C:/code/CopyFolder/Processing"           # must be the processing folder
dest = "C:/code/CopyFolder/Runs"        

listDirs = os.listdir(src)

for i in listDirs:
  os.mkdir(dest + '/' + i)
```

**EDIT: OP changed the question significantly; note that this answer only makes a folder for each folder in the first level below the source folder.**

Comment: this does the trick, great!! for my interest, what does the + '/' do?

Comment: os.mkdir() creates a directory at the specified path. A path is just a string, like the src you posted. But to get from 'C:/code/CopyFolder/Processing' to 'C:/code/CopyFolder/Processing/subFolder' you need to add a slash in between '..Processing' and 'subFolder', otherwise you make the folder 'C:/code/CopyFolder/ProcessingsubFolder'.

Comment: great help! i get it, thnx!

Comment: one question, the script works perfect. Do you know how I can shutil.copytree - in every just created folder - ALL the folders and files from template? I updated the code.